# Converting an entire code from while loop to For loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I have tried converting a code from while loop to For loop but Im not getting the desired output.

The For Loop code is:

```
public static void diamond1() {
        System.out.println("Diamond Height: " + DIAMOND_SIZE);
        System.out.println("Output for: For Loop");

        int noOfRows = DIAMOND_SIZE;
        int md=noOfRows%2;


        //Getting midRow of the diamond
        int midRow = (noOfRows)/2;

        //Printing upper half of the diamond
        for (int i = noOfRows; i >= 0;i=(i-2))
        {
            //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row
            for (int j = 1; j <= i-md; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            //Printing j *'s at the end of each row
            for (int j = 1; j <= (noOfRows+1-md); j++) {
                if (i-md==0 && j==midRow+1) {
                    System.out.print("o ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("* ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        //Printing lower half of the diamond
        for (int i = 2; i <= noOfRows;i=(i+2)) {
            //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            //Printing j *'s at the end of each row
            for (int j=0; j <= (noOfRows); j++) {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

The output that I got was:

```
* * * 
* o * 
  * * * *
```

The output that need is:

```
  * 
* o * 
  *
```

The original while loop I had was:

```
public static void diamond2() {

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Output for: While loop");

    int noOfRows = DIAMOND_SIZE;
    int md=noOfRows%2;

    //Getting midRow of the diamond
    int midRow = (noOfRows)/2;
    int i = noOfRows;
    while(i >= 0){
        //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row
        int j = 1;
        while(j <= i-md){
            if(i-md==0)break;
            System.out.print(" ");
            j++;
        }

        //Printing j *'s at the end of each row
        while(j <= (noOfRows+1-md)){
            if (i-md==0 && j==midRow+1) {
                System.out.print("o ");
            }
            else {
              System.out.print("* ");  
            }
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        i=(i-2);
    }

    i = 2;
    while(i <= noOfRows){
    //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row
        int j = 1;
        while(j <= i){
            System.out.print(" ");
            j++;
        }

        //Printing j *'s at the end of each row
        while(j <= (noOfRows+1-md)){

                System.out.print("* ");
                j++;

        }
                 System.out.println();
                 i=(i+2);
        }

    }
```

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your debugger would help you here.

Comment: @AndyTurner I know this might sound silly but how would I debug this?

Comment: What was the while loop you had originally?

Comment: @donk2017 Use System.out.println() for instance or check tutorials for the IDE that you're using.

Comment: @DaveK. I have edited the OP to include the original while loop.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have tried debugging but unable to find where the mistake is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you used `j` in your while loops you used it as a variable for the original while loop.  In your for loops you are using `j` in your nested for loops which is throwing off your `j` count.  To fix this add in a global int variable and add 2 to it's value at the end of your top diamond loop.  In the bottom loop have it set to the value of `j`+1 at the end of your first nested loop.  Here is what the finished code for your for loops should look like:

```
int count = 0;
//Printing upper half of the diamond
for (int i = noOfRows; i >= 0; i-=2) {
    //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row
    for (int j = 1; j <= i-md; j++) {
        if(i-md==0) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    //Printing j *'s at the end of each row
    for (int j = noOfRows - count; j <= (noOfRows+1-md); j++) {
        if (i-md==0 && j==midRow+1) {
            System.out.print("o ");
        }
        else {
           System.out.print("* ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    count += 2;
}

//Printing lower half of the diamond
count = 0;
for (int i = 2; i <= noOfRows; i+=2) {
    //Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
        count = j+1;
    }
    //Printing j *'s at the end of each row
    for (int j = count; j <= (noOfRows); j++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than comparing the loops you should have concentrated on where the code is going wrong when debugging.  This could have helped you determine where the problem was, and then you could have compared to the original code.

To me a quick look at the last while loop in the lower diamond shows you have the following

```
 //Printing j *'s at the end of each row
        while(j <= (noOfRows+1-md)){
```

But your last for loop has this;

```
//Printing j *'s at the end of each row
            for (int j=0; j <= (noOfRows); j++) {
```

So in the while you are comparing `j <= (noOfRows + 1 - md)`
but in the for loop you are only comparing `j <= noOfRows`

This seems to be the issue.

Comment: I have also tried debugging but unable to figure out where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think just changing the while loops to for loops is not what was intended. Anyhow, there is a straight forward way of accomplishing what you want.

A for-loop in Java has three parts:

- Initial value
- Condition before each iteration
- Action after each iteration

We use this to convert from `while` to `for` in three steps.

1. In the first step, you take all your `while` loops and replace them by a `for` loop with only filling the condition. e.g. `for(;j <= i - md;)`.
2. In the second step you search for the Actions. If you find one, in most cases the last line of your while loops, place them into the action part of the according `for` loop. e.g `for(;j <= i - md; j++)`.
   **Attention! There will be cases where this is not easily possible.**
3. The last step is managing your initial states. Identify occasions where it is possible to provide an initial state to your for loop because the variable is not used outside the scope (after) of a loop. Then you may put the last value assignment as initial state to your loop. e.g. `for(int j=1;j <= i - md; j++)`. **Attention! There will be cases where this is not easily possible.** In your case this step makes no sense at all.

The solution will then look like this:

```
public static void diamond2() {

    System.out.println("Solved by Stackoverflow.com. Have fun with it.");
    System.out.println("Output for: For loops");

    int noOfRows = DIAMOND_SIZE;
    int md = noOfRows % 2;

    // Getting midRow of the diamond
    int midRow = (noOfRows) / 2;
    int i = noOfRows;
    for (; i >= 0; i = (i - 2)) {
        // Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row
        int j = 1;
        for (; j <= i - md; j++) {
            if (i - md == 0)
                break;
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        // Printing j *'s at the end of each row
        for (; j <= (noOfRows + 1 - md); j++) {
            if (i - md == 0 && j == midRow + 1) {
                System.out.print("o ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (i = 2; i <= noOfRows; i = (i + 2)) {
        // Printing i spaces at the beginning of each row
        int j = 1;
        for (; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        // Printing j *'s at the end of each row
        for (; j <= (noOfRows + 1 - md); j++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

By the way, your code is not correct. **It does not work for equal diamond sizes.** If you want to fix this: Throw away your code, sit back and think about *distance to the middle*. Have fun.